# Update record without increment the the id by one

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update the record in my bus table when the `mac` address of the new request is available in the bus table without increment the id each time the row was updated by one but it should be the case when the mac is not available in the bus table. Also is it possible to update the record without incrementing the `id` by one?

I appreciate any help.

**mysql code:**

```
                        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bus
                        (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                        mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                        route int(11) NOT NULL,
                        direction VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
                        latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
                        longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
                        created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)



REPLACE INTO bus(route, direction, latitude, longitude, created_at)
VALUES( ?, ? , ? ,?, now()  )
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean here. Are you looking for an `INSERT IGNORE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` type of trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPLACE is a MySQL extension to the SQL standard. It either inserts, or deletes and inserts.
See
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

So you are always inserting a new row, that is why you get id incremented.

You can use UPDATE to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE BUS
SET ROUTE = value, DIRECTION = value, LATITUDE = value, LONGITUDE = value, CREATED_AT = NOW()
WHERE {CONDITION}
```

remove the curly brackets.

You will need to specify exactly what row (or rows) should be updated after the WHERE statement for example if I want to update the row with id 14 I will use:

```
WHERE ID = 14
```

Cheers